# Mysql query to get info between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

The first is `branches` and has columns `branchid` and `branchname` and others.

The second table is `transfer` and has columns `fromid` and `toid` and others (fromid and to id are branchid )

I want one query to show me names of branches.

Now I do it using two queries:

```
select branchname
from `transfer`, `branches`
where transfer.fromid = branches.branchid
```

and the other query is

```
select branchname
from `transfer`, `branches`
where transfer.toid = branches.branchid
```

Comment: Read about joins in sql: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select bfrom.branchname, bto.branchname
from transfer,branches bfrom, branches bto
where transfer.fromid=bfrom.branchid and transfer.toid=bto.branchid
```

or

```
select bfrom.branchname, bto.branchname
from transfer t
inner join branches bfrom on bfrom.branchid=t.fromid
inner join branches bto on bto.branchid=t.toid
```

Answer (score 0):

We could get it by hitting the branches table only once.

select b.branchname
   from transfer t,branches b
   where t.fromid=b.branchid OR t.toid=b.branchid